# Trying to add a sitemap on aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm running my frontend off of AWS Amplify and I can't figure out how to get the sitemap to appear. It just keeps on saying error 404 on aws amplify. but on localhost it goes straight to it. `robots.txt` works fine on both though.

Here are my AWS Amplify settings. And if it helps, I'm using React

```
[
    {
        "source": "https://www.my-domain.com",
        "target": "https://my-domain.com",
        "status": "301",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "</^((?!\\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|xml)$).)*$/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/sitemap.xml",
        "target": "/sitemap.xml",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Here's also a screenshot
[image]

Anybody know what might be the cause for it going to 404?
I've tried putting sitemap above, below and removing it. Also adding/removing xml from the third setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

1. I removed /sitemap.xml.
2. Then made sure sitemap looked like `sitemap.xml` exactly.
3. Then emptied my cache and did a hard reload.

Even though AWS was updating the URL. It had cached results.

Comment: what to you mean by "removed /sitemap.xml"? why robots.txt is accessible withour a redirect rule whereas to access the sitemap.xml you need to add a redirect rule

Comment: @ChaosLegion I don't see anything wrong here. You can do that. They can answer themselves. There is nothing that goes against the rules here. Also, note that accepting the answer doesn't give them any reputation.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to change the rewrites and redirect settings in AWS Amplify to allow file types ending in .XML to be returned and not forwarded to the root URL (/).

Comment: Please provide snippet of running code